# Creating c++ classes and objects successfully

Tags: c++

I am writing an application in C++ from scratch and right from the beginning I am having trouble defining a class, creating a constructor for it and creating an instance/object of the class. I check the code along as I write it to avoid errors, but when I try to create an object of the class, my problems starts. I will appreciate anyone's help please. It could also be that I am going about it the wrong way creating a class, constructor, etc in c++. I will appreciate  modification of my code and any advice please.
When I run the code below, I get the error messages 'no match for operator <<' and 'invalid operands to binary expression'

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Person
{

public:
    Person(string firstName, string lastName, string nationality, string occupation);

    Person();

    void setFirstName(string firstName)
    {
        this->firstName = firstName;
    }

    void getFirstName()
    {
        cout << firstName;
    }

    void setLastName(string lastName)
    {
        this->lastName = lastName;

    }

    void getLastName(){
        cout << lastName;
    }

    void setNationality(string nationality)
    {
        this->nationality = nationality;
    }

    void getNationality()
    {
        cout << nationality;
    }

    void setOccupation(string occupation)
    {

        this->occupation = occupation;
    }

    void getOccupation()
    {
        cout << occupation;
    }

public:
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string nationality;
    string occupation;

};

int main()
{
    Person p3;
    p3.setFirstName("Larra");
    cout << p3.getFirstName();
    cout << p3.firstName;
        return 0;
}
```

I have changed the code to the one below. But the error message I am getting now is 'collect2:error:Id returned 1 exit status'. How can I fix that please?

````
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Person
{

public:
    Person(string firstName, string lastName, string nationality, string occupation);

    Person();

    void setFirstName(string firstName)
    {
        this->firstName = firstName;
    }

    string getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    void setLastName(string lastName)
    {
        this->lastName = lastName;

    }

    string getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }

    void setNationality(string nationality)
    {
        this->nationality = nationality;
    }

    string getNationality()
    {
        return nationality;
    }

    void setOccupation(string occupation)
    {

        this->occupation = occupation;
    }

    string getOccupation()
    {
        return occupation;
    }

public:
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string nationality;
    string occupation;
};

int main()
{
    Person p3;
    p3.setFirstName("Larra");
    cout << p3.firstName;
        return 0;
}```


******************************************************************
I HAVE FINALLY GOT IT WORKING. THANKS TO EVERYONE THAT HELPED. I  commented out two lines around the start of the program and it started working. You can see the working version below.
******************************************************************

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Person
{

public:
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string nationality;
    string occupation;

public:
    //Person(string firstName, string lastName, string nationality, string occupation);

    //Person();

    void setFirstName(string firstName)
    {
        this->firstName = firstName;
    }

    string getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    void setLastName(string lastName)
    {
        this->lastName = lastName;

    }

    string getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }

    void setNationality(string nationality)
    {
        this->nationality = nationality;
    }

    string getNationality()
    {
        return nationality;
    }

    void setOccupation(string occupation)
    {

        this->occupation = occupation;
    }

    string getOccupation()
    {
        return occupation;
    }

};

int main()
{
    Person p3;
    p3.setFirstName("Larra");
    p3.setLastName("Marrudds");
    cout << p3.firstName << '\n' << p3.lastName <<endl;
        return 0;
}
````

Comment: Errors on which lines?

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  You forgot to `#include <iostream>`

Comment: The errors are from the lines cout << p3.getFirstName();
    cout << p3.firstName;

Comment: `getFirstName` doesn't return anything, actually none of the `get` methods.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica I added that in the code and it was cut off by the text editor for posting. But with that in the code the error still appears.

Comment: @ayedecoder You have `getFirstName()` returning `void`.  It should the string.  `void` isn't something you can print.

Comment: How should my working code look then? I have tried all the suggestions so far and nothing works. I must be doing something really wrong, and I will appreciate your helps please.

Comment: Get rid of `cout << p3.getFirstName();` and change all of your get functions to `string getXXXXX() { return xxxxx; }`

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica I still have errors. I have done as you said by making it look ```public:
    Person(string firstName, string lastName, string nationality, string occupation);

    Person();

    void setFirstName(string firstName)
    {
        this->firstName = firstName;
    }

    string getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }```

Comment: The error message I am getting now is 'collect2:error:Id returned 1 exit status'. Ant idea how to fix that  please?

Answer (score 0):

Overload the constructor for the class, and the operator for the `<<` ostream. This will allow you to use the operator << to output whatever you want using std::cout. Also for the constructor, if you want to not have to set the parameters when declaring the object, you use something like:

```
Person() = default;
```

Then have an alternative set function or another constructor.

Also for your member variables nationality and occupation, your parameters are the same. They must be different.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Person
{

 public:
  string firstName;
  string lastName;
  string Nationality;
  string Occupation;

  Person() = default; // Overload the constructor

  Person(string firstName, string lastName, string n, string o)
  {
    // You could use this also,
    this->firstName = firstName;
    this->lastName = lastName;
    this->Nationality = n;
    this->Occupation= o;
    // etc...
  };



  void setFirstName(string firstName)
  {
    this->firstName = firstName;
  }

  void getFirstName()
  {
    cout << firstName;
  }

  void setLastName(string lastName)
  {
    this->lastName = lastName;

  }

  void getLastName(){
    cout << lastName;
  }

  void setNationality(string nationality)
  {
    this->Nationality = nationality;
  }

  void getNationality()
  {
    cout << Nationality;
  }

  void setOccupation(string occupation)
  {

    this->Occupation = occupation;
  }

  void getOccupation()
  {
    cout << Occupation;
  }

  // Overload operator
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, Person &p)
  {
    os << p.firstName << " " << p.lastName << " " << p.Nationality << " " << p.Occupation;
    return os;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Person p3;

  Person p4("Jack", "Hanson", "Nationality", "Ocupation");

  p3.setFirstName("Larra");

  p3.setLastName ("Hanson");

  cout << p3 << endl;

  cout << p4 << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. I have now solved the problem and I have edited my original post with the working code.